# macOS Mail crashes when window is closed (app brought into background)

Tags: icloud, mail.app, email, crash

For the last year (possibly longer) the Mail app on my iMac crashes after I close the window (not quit, just close using the red X button in the top left corner, or with cmd+w). This happens 100% of the time without fail. I submit a crash report to Apple each time but it seems like this isn't addressed. Note, I only have one account connected and that is my iCloud. Things I've tried:

- resetting PRAM
- removed Mail preferences files
- removed the entire library (can't remember how, found instructions online. but after it was finished the app asked to rebuild the mail index)
- rebuilding mailboxes (https://support.apple.com/guide/mail/rebuild-mailboxes-mlhlp1227/mac)
- removing and re-adding my account

I'm out of ideas besides reinstalling macOS but that's my last resort. Here's part of the crash log:

```
Process:               Mail [10894]
Path:                  /Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail
Identifier:            com.apple.mail
Version:               11.5 (3445.9.1)
Build Info:            Mail-3445009001000000~1
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Mail [10894]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-08-30 11:29:14.606 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G65)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        <STRIPPED>

Sleep/Wake UUID:       <STRIPPED>

Time Awake Since Boot: 45000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010a623000-000000010a9e5000 [ 3848K] r-x/rwx SM=COW   [/Applications/Mail.app/Contents/MacOS/Mail]
```

Edit to add detail:

When I disable my iCloud account in preferences, I can close the app without it crashing. But as soon as the account is re-enabled, it goes right back to crashing on close.

Another thing I noticed is that if I click the "Mailboxes" button to show all mailboxes (eg, Inbox, Flagged, Sent, etc). I can switch to any other mailbox and close the app without problems. It only crashes if I have the Inbox selected and close the app.

**Update:**

Opened Console and tracked error messages from Mail app. Here are the results, all of these errors are logged multiple times except the `AEGetDescData` error.

```
Error sending searchable item 29964 to CoreSpotlight:Error Domain=CSIndexErrorDomain Code=-1000 "(null)"

[AOSAccounts] : [ACAccount+iCloudAccount] : -[ACAccount(iCloudAccount) icaCloudKitToken] - icaCloudKitToken cannot be returned as account is still not vetted!

AEGetDescData of non-desc type 'reco' not a good idea
```

**Update**

A lot of events are logged in Console. I cleared the console before closing Mail, here's a screenshot with all the messages (my email address blurred out).

[image]

Comment: stupid question I know but how do you "Close" mail

Comment: Not a stupid question! Just with the red X button in the top left corner

Comment: Open Console, type Mail in search box so you only see Mail messages, scroll to the bottom, now Close mail and note what message you get.

Comment: Buscar: I get a couple of errors, I'll add details above in the question

Comment: there should be no errors, only two lines informing about the event

Comment: Buscar, I updated the question with a screenshot of the events. It logged a lot of them after closing the window

Comment: Why is reinstalling macOS a last resort?

Comment: BallpointBen: because my dev env takes ages to set up, and my old backup drive died so I'd have to purchase a new one to back up before I reinstall. So I would prefer to not have to reinstall, but if that's what it takes then I'll do it.

Comment: are you aware that the "ScorecardResearch" is quietly sucking your life force ? https://www.scorecardresearch.com/home.aspx

Comment: Haha I did notice that, I'll google how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved itself after installing macOS Mojave! Thanks everyone for the input!

Answer (score 1):

While evaluating your Console report I came across nasty malware on your system called "ScorecardResearch"

Since it is interacting with your Mail and who knows with what else and it is clearly sending your information without your consent, I assume it is also responsible for the Mail error.

Get rid of it.
https://www.2-spyware.com/remove-scorecardresearch-com.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks Buscar, that's the same site I googled yesterday but I didn't find any suspicious apps. I'm pretty careful about what I download. I got rid of any apps that I don't use in a while so hopefully that helps. I also deleted any weird extensions from Chrome. I haven't seen any mentions of scorecard since. As for the Mail app not working, I am trying one more thing: sign out of iCloud completely on the mac and sign back in

Comment: Oops spoke too soon. Scoreshit appeared again. I have no other suspicious apps. Any recommendations on what to do?